# How to implement admob ads with Phonegap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, admob

I want to implement admob ads with phonegap for Android... Is there any guide on how to do this? I've looked around and could only find guides for IOS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [their documentation](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/51172827/HOW%20TO%3A%20Add%20admob%20ads%20to%20your%20phonegap%20application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions specific to using `AdMod/Android` with Phonegap here:

Just check the link given below.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements

You can also find more details about the `generic AdMod SDK/Android setup` here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Which will help you understand the SDK and what exactly you're setting up.

Make sure you click on the Android tab.